# Nightmare.js error code -3

Tags: node.js, electron, nightmare

I'm using `nightmare` to do few commands on a website. My code has few `nightmare` instances nested each other so I can handle the asynchronous call one by one.

Sometimes my script runs successfull, but there are times that somehow `nightmare` throws an error. `error code: -3`.

I've search the Documentation on their github as well on the npm website, but I dont see anything related to error codes.

Does anyone knows what that error means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone knows what that error means?

Those error codes come from Chromium, happening when there's an issue with the underlying navigation.  `-3` is the [navigation abort error code](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/net/base/net_error_list.h?l=31-32), which [Electron (what Nightmare is based on) bubbles up](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-did-fail-load).

> My code has few nightmare instances nested each other so I can handle the asynchronous call one by one.

Asynchronous operations with Nightmare are kind of tricky.  This is getting somewhat offtopic, but can you provide a sample of your source?  I suspect you may have an issue with implementation.

Comment: That was the issue,  I actually printed the error and saw that it was navigation error,  I was having issue because I was looping on those instances, but now I'm Using async module to handle that